# Google App script didn't work in an organization Google Drive

Tags: python, flask, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google app script to write HTML & Flask forms responses when I tested my code on my Google Drive and the Google Sheets was inside my drive the app worked fine but when I changed my Google Sheets location to my organization's Drive it didn't work

that's my google app script code looks like

```
    const sheetName = 'Form Response'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
 const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
 const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
 lock.tryLock(10000)

 try {
   const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
   const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

   const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
   const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

   const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
     return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
   })

   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

   return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
 }

 catch (e) {
   return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
 }

 finally {
   lock.releaseLock()
 }
}
```

I think the problem was here when I deployed the script it was this by default and I couldn't edit it and the app didn't recognize if the person was inside the organization or not

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Feqs.png)